# AVL Tree Recurrence, how is 2*N_2 = O(2^(h/2))

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

I am trying to prove that the height of an AVL tree with N nodes, is at most log N. The proof:

```
N_h = 1 + N_h-2 + N_h-1
    > 2*N_h-2            (1)
    > O(2^(h/2))         (2)
  h < 2*lg N_h           (3)
```

First of all, can anyone explain why `2*N_h-2 > O(2^(h/2))`, I don't seem to understand the algebraic rules at play here. Also, I don't understand how you go from `2*N_h-2 > O(2^(h/2))` to `h < 2*lg N_h`.

Comment: "the number of nodes `N` in an AVL tree is at most `log n`" I think there are exactly `N` nodes in an AVL tree, or am i missing something?

Comment: That was supposed to be log h, updated post

Comment: This still makes no sense. You say that the number of nodes is at most `log h`. This is not possible. I think what you mean is: "The height of an AVL tree with `N` nodes, is at most `log N`". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes my bad ,the height of an AVL tree with N nodes, is at most log N"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an AVL tree, the hieghts of sub-trees of each node differs by at most 1.

Hence if N_h denotes the height of AVL tree with N nodes, then:

```
N_h >= 1 + N_h-1 + N_h-2 ( the heights of both sub-trees can differ by at most one )
    >= 1 + 2*N_h-2
    >= 1 + 2*( 1 + 2*N_h-4 ) (by the same recurrence relation)
     = 1 + 2 + 4*N_h-4
    >= 1 + 2 + 4 + 8*N_h-6
    >= 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +...+ 2^(h/2)
     = 2^(h/2) - 1 (sum of geometric series)

Hence N_h >= 2^(h/2) - 1.
      h/2 <= log(N_h + 1)
      h   <= 2*log(N_h + 1)
Hence h = O(logN)
```

Comment: How do you go from 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +...+ 2^(h/2) to  2^(h/2) - 1?

Comment: @manis This is the sum of a geometric series with common ratio = 2 and having h/2 terms. http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html